# React - FontAwesomeIcon from a variable

Tags: reactjs, refactoring, font-awesome, jsx

I'm choosing the icon conditionally on a function, but when i try to render it fails...

This is what I'm trying:

```js
  getResult = item => {
    let variant;
    let faIcon;
    if (item.result === "UNSTABLE") {
      variant = "#ffc107";
      faIcon = { faExclamationTriangle }
    } else if (item.result === "SUCCESS") {
      variant = "#009688";
      faIcon = { faCheckCircle }
    } 

    return <FontAwesomeIcon size="2x" icon={faIcon} color={variant} />;
  };
}
```

Tried this also:

```js
  getResult = item => {
    let variant;
    let faIcon;
    if (item.result === "UNSTABLE") {
      variant = "#ffc107";
      faIcon = <faExclamationTriangle/>;
    } else if (item.result === "SUCCESS") {
      variant = "#009688";
      faIcon = <faCheckCircle/>
    } 

    return <FontAwesomeIcon size="2x" icon={faIcon} color={variant} />;
  };
}
```

This only work in this way, but it is ugly as hell...

```js
getResult = item => { 
    let variant;
    let faIcon;
    if (item.result === "UNSTABLE") {
      variant = "#ffc107";
      faIcon = { faExclamationTriangle }.faExclamationTriangle;
    } else if (item.result === "SUCCESS") {
      variant = "#009688";
      faIcon = { faCheckCircle }.faCheckCircle;
    } 

    return <FontAwesomeIcon size="2x" icon={faIcon} color={variant} />;
  };
}
```

for sure the problem is lack of some concept...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the code `declarative` (as React is) by moving the state into its own object, making it configurable (instead of imperative `if`s).

```js
const iconMap = {
    "UNSTABLE": {
        color: "#ffc107",
        icon:  { faExclamationTriangle }
    },
    "SUCCESS": {
        color: "#009688",
        icon:  { faCheckCircle }
    },
}


getResult = item => <FontAwesomeIcon size="2x" 
        color={iconMap[item.result].color} 
        icon={iconMap[item.result].icon} />;
    // if you want to pass all props...
    // <FontAwesomeIcon size="2x" {...iconMap[item.result]} />;
```

Adding a support a new state is a matter of adding a new object in `iconMap`.

In fact, above is similar to how [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/) & [Styled-Components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#function-themes) lets you update your themes.

Comment: Other answer works, but this is the correct approach, in my opinion! Thank you!

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that it was `{...}` that was causing the issue... Anyways, glad that you were able to solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

I think replacing

`faIcon = { faExclamationTriangle }.faExclamationTriangle;`

`faIcon = { faCheckCircle }.faCheckCircle;`

with

`faIcon = faExclamationTriangle;`

`faIcon = faCheckCircle;`

will solve your problem.

Comment: it worked! Thank you! Can you explain, or show some doc, why this work and my tests doesnt?

Comment: You are wrapping `faExclamationTriangle`, `faCheckCircle` with braces which is ES6 shorthand syntax for Object literal.
`{ faExclamationTriangle }` is same as `{ faExclamationTriangle:  faExclamationTriangle }.`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
getResult = item => { 
    let variant;
    let faIcon;
    if (item.result === "UNSTABLE") {
        return <FontAwesomeIcon size="2x" icon={{ faExclamationTriangle }.faExclamationTriangle} color={variant} />;
    } else if (item.result === "SUCCESS") {
        return <FontAwesomeIcon size="2x" icon={{ faCheckCircle }.faCheckCircle} color={variant} />;
    } 
  };
}
```

Comment: Yes, for sure... but this is what i was trying to avoid... i have a lot of options, and doesnt make sense fo repeat the <FontAwsome...> every time